# C++ deleting pointer to interface vector memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, memory-leaks, interface

Using: CodeBlocks 13.12, GNU GCC mingw32-g++, Dr.Memory

So I have an assignment to make a vector queue (first in first out).
I made the program and everything worked fine, but in the assignment we need to use an interface IQueue. This interface can not be changed.

```
#ifndef IQUEUE_H
#define IQUEUE_H

template <typename T>
class IQueue {
public:
    virtual void enqueue(const T& element) = 0;
    virtual T dequeue() = 0;
    virtual T front() const = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

This is (some) of my Queue.h just so you get the picture.

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "iqueue.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Queue : virtual public IQueue<T> {
public:
    Queue();
    Queue(int capacity);
    Queue(int capacity, int capacity_increment);
    ~Queue();
    Queue(const Queue<T> &original);
    void operator=(const Queue<T> &original);
    void enqueue(const T& element);
    T dequeue();
    T front() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
private:
    T *items;
    int nr_of_items;
    int capacity;
    void expand(); //expands the array if the nr_of_items is bigger than capacity
    void freeMemory();
};

/*stuff*/

template<typename T>
Queue<T>::~Queue() {
    this->freeMemory();
}
template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::freeMemory() {
    delete[] this->items;
}
```

I'm using freeMemory() in the operator= that's why it's a separate function.

So now to the main

```
#include "iqueue.h"
#include "queue.h"

int main() {

    IQueue<string> *sq = new Queue<string>();

    /*Do stuff with the queue*/

    IQueue<string> *sq2 = new Queue<string>();

    sq2 = sq;

    IQueue<int> *iq = new Queue<int>();

    /*Do stuff with the queue*/

    IQueue<int> *iq2 = new Queue<int>();

    iq2 = iq;

    /*how to delete?*/

    return 0;
}
```

Things I've tested:

1. delete sq;delete sq2;delete iq; delete iq2; with cout in freeMemory() it doesn't run at all.
2. Same as before but I tested making a virtual deconstructor in the IQueue. with cout in freeMemory() it runs once and then crashes. I get 4 unaddressable accesses, 2 invalid heap argument, 2 memory leaks.
   Don't really get what happens here.
3. We haven't used uniqe pointers yet but when I googled around that was suggested as a good method. But I would need a good explanation for my program to know how to do that.
4. Tried vector::erase [cplusplus.com link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).
   Feels like this is the right way to go, however I just get errors about "vector erase used without template class". I've included < vector >.

Any answer that can point me in the right direction is appreciated. General info about why the things I tried didn't work would be nice and give me better understanding.
I'll edit more code in if needed.

Sidenote: We were told you put throw(...) in the .h file if there should be a try catch exception in the function like this:
    virtual T dequeue()throw(…) = 0;
But I just got errors, is this a standard way of doing it?

Comment: 1) you should use virtual destructor. 2) you should track your "items" pointer, when you make the assignment you should make it null. 3) you should check the pointer if it is null or not before deleting it. 4) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IQueue<string> *sq = new Queue<string>();
IQueue<string> *sq2 = new Queue<string>();
sq2 = sq;
```

First memory leak. You lose pointer to sq2 object.

```
IQueue<int> *iq = new Queue<int>();
IQueue<int> *iq2 = new Queue<int>();
iq2 = iq;
```

Second memory leak. Same as above.

Now if you delete pointer to iq1 or iq2 you will have third leak because your interface has no virtual destructor so destructor in your implementation will not be called.

Comment: So if I implement a virtual deconstructor virtual ~IQueue() {};
What do I do to not get memory leaks when copying (I still do get 2 leaks)?

Comment: You probably want to copy objects instead of pointers. Just do it this way: `*sq2 = *sq`.

Comment: Yeah that solves the memory leak problem. But now the new pointer don't have the items the first had. The copy constructor doesn't get used, how do I fix that?

Comment: In this case the copy constructor is not used. `*sq2 = *sq` is done by the assignment operator (`operator=`).

Comment: It doesn't get used either. If I comment out both copy and operator= the program still runs fine which I have no idea why.

Comment: Because if assignment operator is not provided, the compiler can create it implicitly. Read more at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator

Comment: I have an operator= : 
void operator=(const Queue<T> &original); Tried using T instead of void but still doesn't work. I don't know why. I get that it goes to default operator but why when I have assigned one?

Answer (score 0):

Things that I have noticed fron your code and points are:
  1) You are working with pointers. That is, you are actually assigning one pointer to the other. So, operator=() will not be invoked. And memory will leak there.
  2) As you said in your first point, you are deleting sq and then sq2, both of which were pointing to the same memory. Thus heap corruption was detected. Same is happenning with iq and iq2.
  3) Also use virtual destructor.